# Trouble with setting up radar chart data on chart.js; issue with a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, chart.js, radar-chart

I have a plugin I'm coding for wordpress, that uses a short code and provides the ability to choose post types, taxonomies, and colors of the grouped taxonomy terms.. It counts and labels all terms in specified taxonomies, groups them by taxonomy, and plots them on a radar chart using Chart.js with multiple data points per dataset. This version uses the term names as radar chart labels, and the taxonomy names as dataset labels, and colors the datasets based on the taxonomy.

The plugin is working correctly BUT all term counts are always 1 for one iteration of the loop it seems. Because in my data array, I have one round of counts that equal 1 and then all the rest register but with data=0

I know I have the solution but, unsure the best way to implement it?

Code is below:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Taxonomy Radar Chart
 * Description: A WordPress plugin that uses a shortcode to display a radar chart of taxonomy terms. [taxonomy_radar_chart post_types="content" taxonomies="style,tone,difficulty,content-type" colors="#F44336,#9C27B0,#2196F3,#4CAF50"]
 */

function taxonomy_radar_chart_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Parse shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'post_types' => 'post',
            'taxonomies' => 'category',
            'colors'     => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'taxonomy_radar_chart'
    );
    // Get post types and taxonomies as arrays
    $post_types = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['post_types'] ) );
    $taxonomies = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['taxonomies'] ) );

    // Get colors as array, or use default colors
    if ( empty( $atts['colors'] ) ) {
        $colors = array(
            '#F44336',
            '#9C27B0',
            '#2196F3',
            '#4CAF50',
            '#FFEB3B',
            '#795548',
            '#607D8B',
            '#E91E63',
            '#009688',
            '#00BCD4',
            '#FF9800',
            '#CDDC39',
        );
    } else {
        $colors = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['colors'] ) );
    }

    // Get term counts and labels
    $term_counts = array();
    $labels      = array();
    // Loop through post types and taxonomies
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $terms = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                )
            );

            // Loop through terms and get count for each
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_count = wp_count_posts( $post_type, array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $term->slug ) ) ) );
                $term_count = $term_count->publish;

                // Add term count and label to arrays
                $term_counts[ $taxonomy ][ $term->name ] = $term_count;
                $labels[]                                = $term->name;
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove duplicate labels
    $labels = array_unique( $labels );

    // Set up radar chart data
    $datasets = array();
    foreach ( $term_counts as $taxonomy => $counts ) {
        $dataset = array(
            'label'           => $taxonomy,
            'backgroundColor' => array_shift( $colors ),
            'data'            => array(),
        );
        foreach ( $labels as $label ) {
            $dataset['data'][] = isset( $counts[ $label ] ) ? $counts[ $label ] : 0;
        }
        $datasets[] = $dataset;
    }
    // Enqueue Chart.js library
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chartjs', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js', array(), '2.9.3', true );

    // Print chart container
    $chart_id = uniqid( 'taxonomy_radar_chart_' );
    printf(
        '<canvas id="%s" width="400" height="400"></canvas>',
        esc_attr( $chart_id )
    );

    // Print chart script
    $data = array(
        'labels'   => $labels,
        'datasets' => $datasets,
    );
    $options = array();
    printf(
        '<script>
            jQuery(function($) {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("%s").getContext("2d");
                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: "radar",
                    data: %s,
                    options: %s
                });
            });
        </script>',
        esc_attr( $chart_id ),
        wp_json_encode( $data ),
        wp_json_encode( $options )
    );
}
add_shortcode( 'taxonomy_radar_chart', 'taxonomy_radar_chart_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This is almost perfect... **My issue was in the way I was using** `wp_count_posts`. It does not count terms as I thought.

**Now this code uses the** `get_objects_in_term()` function to get an array of post IDs that have the specified term assigned to them, and then it uses the count() function to get the number of posts in that array.

**However**, in the center of the radar chart I have all the data points with a 0 value. Yet, they are also properly mapped out on my chart corresponding to labels. How can I get rid of that and what is going on that this is happening?

New code below:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Taxonomy Radar Chart
 * Description: A WordPress plugin that uses a shortcode to display a radar chart of taxonomy terms. [taxonomy_radar_chart post_types="content" taxonomies="styles,tone,difficulty,content-type" colors="#F44336,#9C27B0,#2196F3,#4CAF50"]
 */

function taxonomy_radar_chart_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Parse shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'post_types' => 'post',
            'taxonomies' => 'category',
            'colors'     => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'taxonomy_radar_chart'
    );
    // Get post types and taxonomies as arrays
    $post_types = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['post_types'] ) );
    $taxonomies = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['taxonomies'] ) );

    // Get colors as array, or use default colors
    if ( empty( $atts['colors'] ) ) {
        $colors = array(
            '#F44336',
            '#9C27B0',
            '#2196F3',
            '#4CAF50',
            '#FFEB3B',
            '#795548',
            '#607D8B',
            '#E91E63',
            '#009688',
            '#00BCD4',
            '#FF9800',
            '#CDDC39',
        );
    } else {
        $colors = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['colors'] ) );
    }

    // Get term counts and labels
    $term_counts = array();
    $labels      = array();
    // Loop through post types and taxonomies
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $terms = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                )
            );

            // Loop through terms and get count for each
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_count = wp_count_posts( $post_type, array( 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $term->slug ) ) ) );
                $term_count = $term_count->publish;

                // Add term count and label to arrays
                $term_counts[ $taxonomy ][ $term->name ] = $term_count;
                $labels[]                                = $term->name;
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove duplicate labels
    $labels = array_unique( $labels );

    // Set up radar chart data
    $datasets = array();
    foreach ( $term_counts as $taxonomy => $counts ) {
        $dataset = array(
            'label'           => $taxonomy,
            'backgroundColor' => array_shift( $colors ),
            'data'            => array(),
        );
        foreach ( $labels as $label ) {
            $dataset['data'][] = isset( $counts[ $label ] ) ? $counts[ $label ] : 0;
        }
        $datasets[] = $dataset;
    }
    // Enqueue Chart.js library
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chartjs', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js', array(), '2.9.3', true );

    // Print chart container
    $chart_id = uniqid( 'taxonomy_radar_chart_' );
    printf(
        '<canvas id="%s" width="400" height="400"></canvas>',
        esc_attr( $chart_id )
    );

    // Print chart script
    $data = array(
        'labels'   => $labels,
        'datasets' => $datasets,
    );
    $options = array();
    printf(
        '<script>
            jQuery(function($) {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("%s").getContext("2d");
                var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: "radar",
                    data: %s,
                    options: %s
                });
            });
        </script>',
        esc_attr( $chart_id ),
        wp_json_encode( $data ),
        wp_json_encode( $options )
    );
}
add_shortcode( 'taxonomy_radar_chart', 'taxonomy_radar_chart_shortcode' );
```